# '"subscriptionKey"' is not assignable to type 'AuthenticationType'. Azure Maps with AngularJ

Tags: angular, azure, azure-maps

I am working with Azure maps in Angular and have an error that I cant seem to find a solution to. According to the azures documentation and samples online it appears to be correct. Anyways my code for authorizing my azures subscription is as following

```
authOptions: {
        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
        subscriptionKey: this.key
      }
```

When I run my angular app it compiles succesfully but gives me an error as following

```
ERROR in src/app/azureMap/azureMap.component.ts:34:9 - error TS2322: Type '"subscriptionKey"' is not assignable to type 'AuthenticationType'.

    34         authType: 'subscriptionKey',
               ~~~~~~~~

      node_modules/azure-maps-control/typings/index.d.ts:4071:9
        4071         authType?: AuthenticationType;
                     ~~~~~~~~
        The expected type comes from property 'authType' which is declared here on type 'AuthenticationOptions'
```

Comment: Shortly after posting this I was able to find my problem. To anyone else that has this problem change it to authType : AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey

Answer (score 0):

AuthenticationType is an Enum for the authType property. Use AuthenticationOptions instead. For example:

```
authOptions: AuthenticationOptions = {
    authType: <AuthenticationType>'subscriptionKey',
    subscriptionKey: this.key
}
```